# How to disable X-Powered-By on OVH mutualized server using apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I tried to disable both `X-Powered-By` and `Server` for security concerns by adding the following to my .htaccess in a OVH mutualized server.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Security disable headers. http://www.shanison.com/2012/07/05/unset-apache-response-header-protect-your-server-information/
  Header unset Server
  Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work, I still get these headers when running HTTP requests. Why? It is not possible because somehow the mod_headers.c is not loaded on a mutualized server?

Comment: Still looking for a solution here.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a PHP function as well which is able to do this:

```
<?php
header_remove("X-Powered-By");
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Hope this help

Comment: Note that `Removes an HTTP header previously set using header().` it may not work in every case tho. Header defined by something else than PHP `header` function may not be impacted.

Comment: Putting this piece of code into the Constructor should work

Comment: It totally depends upon your framework, since it's a header change it's most definitely required to apply this before the headers are sent to the client.

Answer (score 4):

you can add these lines to your .htaccess

```
Header always unset X-Powered-By
Header unset X-Powered-By
```