# Trying to resolve "The X-powered header is sent within the response header."

Tags: apache, nginx, http-headers, plesk

I am trying to address the above issue which is cropping up in SEO.

The following solution is the one that is suggested:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Unset Server Signature header
    ServerSignature Off
    # Unset Server Technology header
    Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Set XSS Protection header
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

I have put this in the "Additional Apache Directives", but to no avail. My server hosting company don't seem to be able to help. I am not getting any syntax errors with this. It just doesn't seem to work.

I am running Plesk 12.5.30 Update #71 on CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 (Core)‬. Apache and nginx.

Any help would be appreciated, as I am tearing my hair out with this now!

Comment: Is this directly in httpd.conf or in some other .conf file?  If it is in another file, make sure that other file is included from httpd.conf, and not commented out.

Comment: Depending on the content that being served, those directives may need to be added to nginx additional directives too, for example:
add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

or, apache directives may be written in domain's .htaccess

Also, did you try to add this one: proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

Comment: It's in the Additional Apache Directives. Following your suggestion, I have put the following into the additional nginx directives:

    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have worked either.

Comment: You got an answer here in php to remove special header  [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822080/how-to-disable-x-powered-by-on-ovh-mutualized-server-using-apache/40299534